# Using recursion to print strings in C

Tags: c, recursion

Let me start with saying I am not looking for someone to do this for me. I am hoping for a hint or suggestion.

I know there is a smarter way to do this. Code is posted below. I am trying to print an outline. My code works up to a depth of 3. (The depth is the number of subsections - so 3 would be section 1, section 1.A, and section 1.A.1). It also works for a width (number of sections and each type of subsection) of 26, where it is capped. However, to get a larger depth, it would involve many more loops. Not only is that terrible code, it also freezes up the terminal I'm working on.
I believe recursion would make it much nicer, but I'm struggling to grasp the idea when using a string (I understand when it is a number).Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sec(int width, int snum) {

    char section[100];
    sprintf(section, "Section ");
    printf("%s %i", section, snum);
    return 0;
}

int ssec_num(int width, int i) {
    char num[100];
    sprintf(num, "%i", i);
    printf(".%s", num);
}

int ssec_let(int width, char z) {
    char let[100];
    sprintf(let, ".%c", z);
    printf("%s", let);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int depth = atoi(argv[1]);
    int width = atoi(argv[2]);
    int sec_int=1;
    int sec_wid = width;
    int let_wid;
    int num_int;
    int num_dep;
    int num_wid;
    int dep;
    char z = 'A';

    while(sec_wid > 0) {
        sec(width, sec_int);
        let_wid = width;
        dep = depth-1;
        printf("\n");
        while(dep > 0) {
            while(let_wid > 0) {
                num_wid = width;
                num_int = 1;
                sec(width, sec_int);
                ssec_let(let_wid, z);
                printf("\n");
                num_dep = depth-2;
                    while(num_dep > 0) {
                        while(num_wid > 0) {
                            sec(width, sec_int);
                            ssec_let(let_wid, z);
                            ssec_num(width, num_int);
                            num_wid--;
                            num_int++;
                            printf("\n");
                            num_dep--;
                        }
                    }
                let_wid --;
                z++;
            }
            dep --; 
        }
    sec_int++;
    sec_wid--;
    z = 'A';
    } 
 }
```

If `depth` is 3 and `width` is 2 then it would be

```
Section 1
 Section 1.A
  Section 1.A.1
  Section 1.A.2
 Section 1.B
  Section 1.B.1
  Section 1.B.2
Section 2
 Section 2.A
  Section 2.A.1
  Section 2.A.2
 Section 2.B
  Section 2.B.1
  Section 2.B.2
```

Comment: Show what output you want for what input.

Comment: I see no recursion here, just nested loops.

Comment: @Baldrickk : OP thinks recursion is a good thing for whatver he want's to do (I haven't been able to figure this out though).

Comment: In 95% of the cases, recursion is never smarter/better than anything else, but rather the opposite...

Comment: I tried depth 4 and width 2 and I get:
Section  1
Section  1.A
Section  1.A.1
Section  1.A.2
Section  1.B
Section  1.B.1
Section  1.B.2
Section  2
Section  2.A
Section  2.A.1
Section  2.A.2
Section  2.B
Section  2.B.1
Section  2.B.2
Is this the expected behavior? Why isn't there a Sections 1.A.1.A ?

Comment: @igon Because that would require yet another loop. I felt as though that would get far too cumbersome since it needs to get to a depth of 10 and width of 26.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you described uses a `width` to declare how many times each (sub)section is repeated. This kind of repetition you can achieve with a loop.

The algorithm also uses a `depth` to determine how many (sub)sections you have. Here is the tricky part, and you can use recursion to solve it. A recursive function is basically a function that calls itself a limited number of times. There must always be a condition to stop the recursion, otherwise the function would call itself until the call stack overflows, abnormally stopping the program execution.

For your problem, you can have a function that receives a counter, that determines at with (sub)section depth it currently is. It would loop `width` times (as described above) and call itself `depth` times, until the counter reaches the value of `depth`. This way, you'll have a function that has a `depth` number of (sub)sections, each with a `width` number of items.

As you need to print the (sub)sections at the previous depths, you can use a buffer to store the section values at each depth, like `int buffer[MAX_DEPTH];`, with `#define MAX_DEPTH 100` to set the maximum depth your program supports.

Then you'll have something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DEPTH 100

void print_section(const int *const buffer, const int current_depth) { 
    // print all the (sub)section values stored at the buffer so far
    // use a loop like for (i = 0; i <= current_depth; i++)
}

void recursive(int *const buffer, const int current_depth, 
        const int depth, const int width) {
    if (current_depth < depth) {
        // continue recursion
        int current_width;
        for (current_width = 1; current_width <= width; current_width++) {
            buffer[current_depth] = current_width;
            print_section(buffer, current_depth);
            recursive(buffer, current_depth + 1, depth, width);
        }
    }
    // else stop recursion
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // ...
    int buffer[MAX_DEPTH];
    recursive(buffer, 0, depth, width);
    return 0;
}
```

You'll also need some extra logic to determine when to print a letter or a number at each (sub)section depth.

**EDIT:** To print the (sub)section title just use the following

```
void print_section(const int *const buffer, const int current_depth) { 
    int i;
    printf("Section ");
    for (i = 0; i <= current_depth; i++) {
        printf(i == 0 ? "%i" : ".%i", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm going to go down the same path of a lot of loops in order to determine what should be in each subsection. I think I'd end up with 10 loops total - 1 for the header Section and then 9 for each potential subsection.